# syncing a model to asp.net server using backbonejs and jquery

Tags: javascript, asp.net, rest, backbone.js, underscore.js

I wanted to see how i could save a model to server using `model.save()` method when `urlRoot` is specified on the extended model, but ajax request never fires when i ask for `model.fetch()` or `do model.save()`. note: Is hope this is possible without using Collection i suppose?.

#### HTML

```
<div id="placeholder"></div>
<script type="text/template" id="view_template">
    Hello <%= name %>, here is your script <%= script %>
</script>
```

#### Model

```
 window["model"] = Backbone.Model.extend({
        initialize: function () {
            console.log("CREATED");
        },
        defaults:{
            name:"Please enter your name",
            script:"Hello World"
        },
        urlRoot: "index.aspx",
        validate: function (attrs) {

        },
        sync: function (method, model, success, error) {
            console.log("SYNCING", arguments);
        }
    });
```

#### View

```
 window["view"] = Backbone.View.extend({
        template:_.template($("#view_template").html()),
        initialize: function () {
            console.log("INITIALISED VIEW");
            this.model.bind("change","render",this);
        },
        render: function (model) {
                console.log("RENDERING");
                $(this.el).append(this.template(model));
                return this;
        }
    });
```

#### Application

```
$("document").ready(function () {

    var myModel = new model({
        name: "Stack Overflow",
        script: "alert('Hi SO')"
    });

    var myView = new view({
        model: myModel,
        el: $("#placeholder")

    });

    console.log("SAVING");
    myModel.save();        
    console.log("FETCHING");
    myModel.fetch();


});
```

as you can see in application i call `save & fetch` but as per documentation this should fire ajax request with `POST -> SAVE` & `GET -> FETCH`. But all it does is log's arguments into console in the sync function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only reason you are not seeing any Ajax requests is that you have overridden the Model.sync method. Normally you would only do this if you wanted to replace the default Ajax syncing implemented in Backbone.sync. See the following line in Model.fetch in backbone.js:

```
return (this.sync || Backbone.sync).call(this, 'read', this, options);
```

I did a quick test with your code and I am seeing the Ajax requests if I rename your Model.sync method.

Comment: awesome :) i found it out after reading the docs correctly. btw could you look into this question too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7670709/invalid-web-service-call-missing-value-for-parameter-with-backbone-and-webservic

Comment: Looking at the other question I can now see why you might need to override sync. I haven't ever had to wire ASP.NET Web Services with backbone.js.